# Rebalance/move or strink oracle undotablespace

Tags: oracle, tablespaces

I'm running out of space in oradata01 and oradata02. Is there a ways to move or rebalance with oradata03?

```
/opt/oracle/oradata01/x/undotbs01.dbf   4   100 %   
/opt/oracle/oradata02/x/undotbs02.dbf   17  100 %   
/opt/oracle/oradata03/x/undotbs03.dbf   25  1 %
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on 12c then it's easy - just online move datafile.

```
SQL> ALTER DATABASE MOVE DATAFILE '/opt/oracle/oradata02/x/undotbs02.dbf' TO '/opt/oracle/oradata03/x/undotbs02.dbf';
```

If you are on lower version, and if you can afford stopping instance, then

1) shutdown database

2) move datafile to oradata03 by os command

3) mount database

4) rename datafile

```
SQL> ALTER DATABASE rename file '/opt/oracle/oradata02/x/undotbs02.dbf' TO '/opt/oracle/oradata03/x/undotbs02.dbf';
```

If you can't stop the instance, then you can create another undo tablespace and switch to it online.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/undo005.htm#ADMIN11470

You can also try to resize datafiles, it will work, if there are no active/retention undo segments at the end of datafiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a new undo Ts and drop the old one .

`show parameter undo`

NAME TYPE VALUE

---

undo_management string AUTO

undo_retention integer 900

undo_tablespace string UNDOTBS1

`SQL> CREATE UNDO TABLESPACE undotbs2 DATAFILE '+DATA_NEWPATH' SIZE 100M AUTOEXTEND ON;`

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/AutomaticUndoManagement.php

`SQL> alter system set undo_tablespace=undotbs2;`

After that can drop UNDOTBS1. [Take a look here for more information.](https://community.oracle.com/thread/921889?start=0&tstart=0)

Regards